# Find open set according to a boundary

Tags: general-topology

I'm beginning in topology and wondering how could I find three different open sets such as the boundary of the sets are $\{((x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y=0)\}$

Thanks

Comment: use half-planes to get two sets immediately.

Comment: Depends on the topology but with euclidean one: $\{(x,y):y\neq 0\},\{(x,y):y<0\},\{(x,y):y>0\}$

Comment: Thank you for your help, now if I want to find three close sets with euclidian topology such as the interior of the space is $((x,y): \ x^2+y^2 \ < 1)) \ U \ ((x,y): (x-3)^2+y^2<1))$ How could we proceed ?

Comment: To find those closed set just take the closed hull and then add some random isolated points outside that (the interior of that will still be the original set since the interior of isolated points is empty).